# Class styling not being recognized

Tags: css

I'm designing a profile page for my website and I have the following div setup:

```
<div class="profile-first-block-wrap">
    <div class="profile-first-block">
        <h2 class="maintitle">My Profile</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Username: <?php echo $_SESSION['user_name']?></li>
            <li>Email Address:  <?php echo $_SESSION['user_email']?></li>
            <li>Account Type: <?php echo $UAC_base->getUACTitle()?></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what's going on for the classes *profile-first-block-wrap* and *profile-first-block* in my stylesheet:

```
.profile-first-block-wrap{
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    display: block;
}

.profile-first-block{
    width: 1200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Now, the key thing to remember here is that I have this exact same div setup on other pages of my site, but they're called - for example - *about-first-block-wrap*. The classes have the exact same styling and if I change the class of my div's to say - *about-first-block-wrap* and *profile-first-block* - then everything works fine.

When I inspect element on the page and select my div - it doesn't even recognize the fact that the class has styling in my stylesheet. I have absolutely no idea why this is happening. I faced this problem earlier on when I was doing another page, but it kind of just fixed itself when I was playing around with things - though I have no clue what specifically solved my problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please see how to create a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) -- just seeing the code that works is not helpful in working out why some code that you haven't included isn't working! ;)

Comment: Could have been your cache. I suspect the changes didn't happen immediately (assuming the styles were applied on other elements within different pages and that it has nothing to do with how you've connected the stylesheets per page).

Comment: @bigal - thanks, for some reason I did not think about clearing the cache. Seemed so trivial. That seemed to do the trick. Ta!